# Is it possible to create a control in C++ and use in Java activity?

Tags: android, c++, custom-controls

I want to create a control in `C++` and use it in my `java` based activity. Just like we create an instance of `TextView` or `ImageView`, I want to create an instance of my native control and show it in some Java based activity's view. Is it possible first of all? If yes are there any tutorials or demo related to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "native control" in Android. Your UI widgets need to be written in Java.